# Call class method of Objective C category

Tags: objective-c, class-method, objective-c-category

AFNetworking has a class method called `+ af_sharedImageCache` that I want to access from my own category, but I can't figure out the syntax to reference this. Internally it is doing `[[self class] af_sharedImageCache]` but obviously that's not gonna work for me. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `+ af_sharedImageCache` is a private method, not exposed on `UIImageView+AFNetworking.h`. You can call it, though, using Obj-C runtime.

```
if ([[self class] respondsToSelector:@sel(af_sharedImageCache)]) {
     NSCache *cache = [[self class] performSelector:@sel(af_sharedImageCache)];
}
```

However, `AFImageCache` is a private class, and you would have to do the same hack to use its methods. If I were you, I'd create my own cache, as it's clear that `AFNetworking` doesn't want that you mess with its cache implementation.

Comment: I'm leaning towards that now anyway. It's literally just an `NSDictionary` keyed on a url. Not exactly complicated.

Comment: It's not an `NSDictionary`, it's an `NSCache`, which behaves like an `NSDictionary` but evicts objects to free memory if needed. You can read more about it on [this nice article on NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/nscache/).